# Where can I find out the meaning of @endpoints.method parameters?

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints

I can see that the following @endpoints.method accepts several different kinds of parameters.

```
@endpoints.method(message_types.VoidMessage, ProfileForm,
            path='profile', http_method='POST', name='saveProfile')
```

Where can I read more about what these parameters are and and potentially also other `@endpoints.` functions exist and what their parameters are?

I have googled for documentation, but all I have found are articles and getting started guides. I haven't been able to find any comprehensive explanation of what endpoints functions exist, what they return and what their parameters are.

Answer (score 0):

The [official Python documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/create_api) has the decorator parameters documented.